# SQL Server: how to reference a foreign key to another table where the key is named differently

Tags: sql-server, reference, relationship

Trying to write the script to reference a foreign key in another table that is named differently. Here's part of my script, see if you can figure out what im trying to do, I don't know a better way to explain it:

```
ALTER TABLE journal
ADD CONSTRAINT journal_authorid_FK FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES employee.emp_id;
```

as you can see, the author_id in one table references the emp_id primary key in another table. Reason being is that there is already a key in this table called emp_id.The emp_id FK in this table will be used to identify who this journal entry pertains to. The author_id is the person that made the entry. Obviously they are both located on the employee table. How do I make this relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE journal
ADD CONSTRAINT journal_authorid_FK FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id);
```